# Is this a min-heap?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I want to find all pairs of numbers in a list that sum to `n`.

If I build a tree with the property that the children of of each node is all the values larger than itself, then I will be able to traverse it to find all the combinations that sum to `n`:

eg. for list `[1,2,3,4]`:

```
                   1

      2            3           4

   3     4         4           

4
```

What kind of data structure is this?

Is it a min-heap with no constraint on the number of children per node and duplicates permitted?

Comment: I think you get to name it, maybe a benaston heap. It rolls off the tongue well.

Comment: How does this structure help with that goal? If your `n=7`, then the topmost node `1` doesn't help you find `3+4`. If your input was `[1, 3, 4]` and `n=7`, then `1` doesn't contribute to any result at all.

Comment: My intention is to do a depth first traversal, maintaining a pair (prev, curr) at each node and continuing the traversal accordingly. Is this not going to work? Just a guess currently. A traversal for for n === 7: `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4 - record), (2,4), (1,3), (3,4 - record, discard), (1,4)`

Comment: It seems like a very time- and space-inefficient solution to the problem (your tree will have elements proportional to O(n^2) of the size of the original list, and the algorithm will iterate that many times over the tree as well), which you can solve in linear time and space with a hash table.

Comment: Please can you describe the hash table approach?

Comment: Hint: Just sort your list, and you'll have the equivalent of your data structure - each linked list node is followed by all those that are larger than it.

Comment: @Bergi, gets us down to O(n log n), but we can still do better.

Comment: @Welbog I wasn't trying to solve the problem, it was just a thought on the data structure and its usefulness. Given that, it's quite unlikely a name for this structure exists because nobody would use it.

Comment: @Bergi, fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target number is `N`. You can keep a hash table containing numbers you've encountered so far, and when you encounter a new number `X`, you can test whether you've encountered `N-X` in your hash table.

Pseudocode:

```
var encountered <- hashTable(key: integer, value: any)
var recordList <- list(value: pairs of integers)
for each element in inputList
  if encountered(N-element) then push [element, N-element] into recordList 
  push element into encountered
loop
return recordList
```

Comment: This is ingenious

Comment: I was asked to do something similar in an interview. I had a less efficient solution and was given the hint to use a hash table and this is what I came up with.